# Formatting resume header!

Tags: titles, cv

Earlier I created a resume successfully and it was easy thanks to your support :) I noticed that my resume tends to be big and consume too much space and after reading some PR interview I am thinking of revisiting my resume.

[image]

Now I was trying to go for something like above but unfortunately I wasn't able to replicate the above format.

I tried using `tables`  but I wasn't able to format the text inside it nor I was able to provide line break (in one cell- as show in address and contact above)

It'd be great if you can help me a bit since similar format is followed throughout the resume :)

Comment: Do you have recommendation in terms of the document class? Is `article` okay?

Comment: yes , I am using `article` style only :)

Comment: Any help on this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I'm unfamiliar with the extent of this usage, the following is an adequate replica that could be extended (I assume) to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\sffamily%
{\small\begin{tabular}[c]{l}
  123 Spruce St, Apt 35 \\
  Philadelphia PA 19103
\end{tabular}}\hfill%
{\Large\bfseries\begin{tabular}[c]{c}
  GAYLE LAAKMANN
\end{tabular}}\hfill%
{\small\begin{tabular}[c]{r}
  (555) 555-1212 \\
  gayle@careerup.com
\end{tabular}}%

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
  \textbf{Employment} \\
  \hline
  {\bfseries Software Engineer, Intern \qquad Apple Computer \hfill Summer 2004} \\
  \quad iChat AV
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The title is set using vertically `c`entered `tabular`s, while the subsequent structure detailing experience/employment is set in a `p`aragraph-style `tabular`, the width of which spans exactly `\linewidth`.

Comment: I did everything as mentioned but the text appear on the left side :/

Comment: Ok it worked :) Thanks :) Seems like a single `linebreak` between command was breaking things apart! 

BTW any idea of giving Teletype (Typewriter) style fond to address and phone ? When I tried `\texttt` it just make things bigger and worse and doesn't looks like Teletype at all!

Comment: You tried `\texttt{(555) 555-1212}` and `\texttt{gayle@careerup.com}`? Works for me as you can see in [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/esi9q.png).

Comment: Yes that works - seems like `\texttt` wasn't scaling on multiple line maybe its not accepting line break! BTW any help on new problem ?

Comment: Is there anyway I can separate Header Title (Employment) and `\hline` from the above format yet attain the same alignment? Cause when I try I get errors !